# Black sreen when running Kivy app in socket server

Tags: python, sockets, kivy

I want to update self.string in kivy window each time the socket object receives data from the client socket but the screen remains in black. Why is this happening?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
import socket
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import time


# Basic class Float Layout
class MyWidget(GridLayout):

    string = ObjectProperty('')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       
        self.register_event_type('on_custom_event')
        self.cols = 1
        self.string = Label(text = 'Server Started')
        
    def dispatch_event(self,*args):

        self.dispatch('on_custom_event', "test_message")

    def on_custom_event(self, *args):

        # Get data from serial port
        c, addr = s.accept()
        value = c.recv(1024) 

        if value != []:
            value = value.decode('utf-8')  
            print("value",value)
       
            text = "Bienvenido {0}"
            data = text.format(value)
            self.string.text = data
        return self.string

def callback(*args):
    print('Bienvenido {}', args)

# Main App class
class MyApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def build(self):
        w = MyWidget()
        w.bind(on_custom_event = callback)
        refresh_time = 5
        Clock.schedule_interval(w.dispatch_event, refresh_time)
        return w

# Main program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Connect to serial port first
    host = 'Localhost' 
    port = XXX
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    try:
        s.bind((host, port)) 
        print("socket binded to port", port)
        s.listen(5) 
    except:
        print('Failed to connect') 
        exit()
  
    MyApp().run()
    c.close()
```

Every time the socket server recieves data from the client, a new event is supposed to be created. This event should create a new string with the same data and the object string should be updated in the kivy window.

Answer (score 1):

In your `MyWidget` class the `__init__()` method creates a `Label`, but never adds it to the `MyWidget`. To fix it just add that `Label`:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   
    self.register_event_type('on_custom_event')
    self.cols = 1
    self.string = Label(text = 'Server Started')
    self.add_widget(self.string)  # add the Label to MyWidget
```